# Setting a fixed routeValue in .NET Core's CreatedAtAction/CreatedAtRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I have a Web API that allows basic CRUD using GET/POST/PUT, but also contains subobjects that are accessed through `/apipath/MyObject/{objectId}/SubObject/{subObjectId}`

Adding a subObject uses this method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id}/Members")]
    [Produces(typeof(TeamMember))]
    public IActionResult AddTeamMember(Guid id, [FromBody] TeamMember teamMember)
    { 
      //some processing here.
      return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetMember), new { id, memberId = teamMember.Id }, teamMember);
    }
```

The GetMember method looks like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}/Members/{memberId}")]
    public IActionResult GetMember(Guid id, Guid memberId)
    { //processing here
    }
```

Calling CreatedAtAction in `AddTeamMember` throws a

> 'System.InvalidOperationException': No route matches the supplied values.

If I change the Route tag of `GetMember` to exclude the Members part, it works. So, how do I tell CreatedAtAction that there's supposed to be a `Members` in between id and `memberId`?

Comment: Are the two actions are in same controller and what is the Location header of the response ?

Comment: Yes the two actions are in the same controller. Since I'm getting an exception calling AddTeamMember I can't tell you what the location header is. It is supposed to be /api/Teams/{teamId}/Members/{memberId} whereas the /api/Teams part is in the RoutePrefix of the controller.